# How to bind query to row function in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Hi I'm new here studying google spreadsheet query function to do some jobs. Here is the example file that I'm working for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gpnZ2XmZbPaZVjMa734dXLHJmydnAG_YXW7V_LBXGRU/edit?usp=sharing

First tab "All_data" contains ever growing list of data. And I made a second tab "Recent" to pull out the most recent 200 rows from All_data in reverse order. As a practice, I'm just playing with the first column. First, I was able to pull the recent 200 rows with this code `=query(All_data!A2:A,"offset "&(counta(All_data!A2:A)-200),0)` Then I found on the internet `=SORT(Range_to_sort, ROW(values_in_order), false)` can reverse the order of range. The sort worked when I tried with just plain text range(Column B of Recent tab) - actually I'm not sure how it works. I thought row(values_in_order) should return only a single value since it's not an arrayformula. But somehow it works.

Anyway, when I tried to bind query to row like`=row(query(All_data!A2:A,"offset "&(counta(All_data!A2:A)-200),0))` it returns #NA instead of value. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is something like `=sort(query(All_data!A2:A,"offset "&(counta(All_data!A2:A)-200),0), row(query(All_data!A2:A,"offset "&(counta(All_data!A2:A)-200),0)),false)`

Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your objective to get a single formula to do both the the query, and the reverse sort?  Or did you want a sort formula where you didn't need to hard code the range?  I can help with the latter, if that's what you need.  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  That trick for reversing a column is new to me.  Don't know how it works.  But if you are just looking to avoid hard coding the range A2:A200, I got that to work using INDIRECT.

```
=sort(indirect("A2:A"&counta(A2:A)+1),row(indirect("A2:A"&counta(A2:A)+1)),false)
```

So this would work if you had a helper column (Column A) return the query results, and then this formula reverses the sort order, regardless of how many values you had.  But if you are always going to have 200 records, then your current formula is already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this answer separately for now, since my other answer may still be useful.

See my tab "Recent-GK" in your sheet for the working result.

Reading up on the sort syntax explains how the reversing works. You're just giving a list of numbers - ROW(A2:A5) gives 2,3,4,5 - to use for the sort order.
And using the reverse flag for the sort order, makes it sort them backwards.

So we don't need to worry about the range of the query results, we just need to know the length of the range.  Then we can use any virtual column to use with the ROW(range) part of the sort.  If you know you'll always have 200 records returned from the query, you can do the following:

```
=SORT(QUERY(All_data!A2:A,"OFFSET "&(COUNTA(All_data!A2:A)-200),0),ROW(A1:A200),FALSE)
```

If there is a chance you might not get 200 records, you could return the query results into a temporary helper column, do a COUNTA to count the records, and then use indirect as in my eaarlier answer to adjust the ROW(range) to match the number of records.

Let me know if this helps.